# show full xmlDoc in Visual Studio Intellisense/Resharper Autocomplete Tooltip?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, intellisense, xml-documentation

I have some problems using Intellisense/Resharper in my Visual Studio 2012.

When Autocomplete shows me class members i'd like to see the complete xmlDoc as Tooltip. The closest i came was using Resharper and activate "show Summary" in "Completion Appearance" Options. But what about the parameter description, return type text, ...?

I am used to autocomplete from java Eclipse and i really miss this in Visual Studio. 
Perfect would be to see the same tooltip when hoovering the mouse over a class member.

Does anyone know how to get this?

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper can show a "QuickDoc" view, which provides the full xml documentation, nicely formatted. The tooltip view is just the summary. To activate the QuickDoc, use ctrl-q, or ReSharper -> Edit -> Show Quick Documentation. See here for more: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Quick_Documentation.html

Comment: Or `Ctrl+Shift+F1` in VS Scheme

Comment: This looks really nice. Can i show this in Resharpers Completion/Autocomplete?

Comment: Not all of it, no. But ReSharper does show the summary tag in code completion and parameter info.